# groupBy method can't insert or save a multiple values

Tags: php, laravel, group-by, laravel-5

I'm thinking why I can't insert or save the tables that I groupBy in the statement that I did. I group them properly but when I tried to insert this into my database it just get the first value in the column not all the values. I have a one to many relationship between **departments** and **users**

Die and Dump

[image: SC]

As you can see here in "Department of Engineering" I have a users id which is **3** and **4**. When I tried to insert this into database the first value is only that inserted.

Database Values

[image: SC]

Controller

```
public function getDocuments()
 {
   $departmentRecipient = DB::table('users')->select('departments.department_name', 'users.id', DB::raw('group_concat(users.id)'))
    ->join('departments', 'departments.id', '=', 'users.department_id')
    ->groupBy('departments.department_name')
    ->get();
 }

public function postDocuments(Request $request)
{


    $document = new Document();
                                //Request in the form
    $document->title = $request->title;
    $document->content = $request->content;
    $document->category_id = $request->category;

    $document->save();

    $user = Auth::user();

    foreach($request->recipient as $recipientId)
    {
        $document->sentToUsers()->sync([ $recipientId => ['sender_id' => $user->id]],false );
    }

}
```

View

```
<div class = "form-group">

    <label for = "recipient" class = "control-label">Recipient:</label>

    <select name = "recipient[]" multiple class = "form-control select2-multi" id = "myUserList">

        @foreach ($departmentRecipient as $list)
            <option value = "{{ $list->id }}">{{ $list->department_name }}</option>
        @endforeach

    </select>

</div>
```